# Вывод комментариев в блоге

Tags: кодировка, php

Пишу блог по по видео урокам Попова, до шел до вывода комментариев к заметкам. Все написал как было показано. Но у меня не отображается русский шрифт при отправки комментов. Когда вместо русского либо вопросы либо другая белеберда, это я понять могу. Ставишь кодировку везде одну и тоже и все работает. А тут вообще ничего, не в Бд не отображается не на странице. Дата выводится правильно.

> Комментарий добавил(-а): *тут имя автора*
> Дата: 2013-01-16
> *тут полный текст*

А вот англ. буквы выводятся отлично, все как и должно быть. Не знаю что делать, помогите.

Comment: Вероятно, проблема всё-таки в кодировке таблиц базы данных. Перепроверьте, чтобы там стояла кодировка, поддерживающая кириллицу, например, utf8. Попробуйте пересоздать БД в этой кодировке.

Comment: Спасибо помогло, комментарии теперь и русские тоже выводятся. Только в БД теперь русский не отображается и весь текст в блоге вопросами заменился. В бд стоит сравнение с utf8_general_ci. И при подключении БД (SET NAMES cp1251 или utf8) - непомогает.

Answer (score 3):

Кодировку в PHP файле напиши:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

В .htaccess напиши:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```